# Good free online PDFs for probability and statistics (with practice problems and answers)?

Tags: probability, statistics, online-resources

I'd like to rebuild from the ground up and really make sure I have a strong grasp on probability and statistics.

I am able to compute answers in a pinch but I'd like a more formal understanding so I can really ensure I am being systematic about it. For example I have no idea what a probability mass/density function is.

Are there any good resources that go over all the basics and fundamentals while also providing answers to check my work against?

Answer (score 1):

A warm suggestion: Go online to half.com or amazon and look for a used statistics book. You don't need the latest version (expensive), you can also go for a previous version (=cheap, I would have given you mine for free if you had lived around the corner). My favorite: Introduction to statistics by Mario Triola, from which I taught the course couple of semesters to nursing students. I liked the book, good explanations and examples. (But there are other stats books as well).  The answers (odds) are in the back, stats tables are with it too, and if not, those are available on the internet as well. You got everything in one book instead of bunch of PDF's. And if you get stuck on a problem, post it on MSE and we can help...Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Happen to have any cold suggestions?

Comment: Here is a link to the book I taught from: https://www.amazon.com/Mario-F-Triola-Elementary-Statistics/dp/B004K3BHTQ  Including shipping you're done for less than 10 bucks

Comment: Want to go little recent, here is the 11th edition (for approx $15): https://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Statistics-11th-Mario-Triola/dp/0321500245  I also checked the 12 edition which is presumably the current edition, way too expensive. Same material wrapped in a different cover = not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in understanding probability theory/statistics or just using probability theory/statistics? You say "build from the ground up" and to me that means diving straight into measure theory. On the other hand, you might have never even taken a calculus class, which will make understanding what a probability density function is very difficult as, given a random variable $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ it is defined as the Radon-Nikodym derivative of a probability distribution (an induced measure) $\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(\omega))$ with respect to $\mu$, the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. For basic statistics, this is unnecessary but for a deeper understanding and for some applications, it is VERY necessary. Can you elaborate on your background/goals?

Comment: Anything and everything. My calculus class in high school was not great (I can use derivatives and integration and set up problems, but I honestly have no idea how calculus works). I enjoy proving things that I otherwise take for granted, because I like feeling confident in knowing how and why something works.

Comment: Well in that case, your best bet is to get to the point where you do know how calculus works and then start out with some basic measure theory. You don't have to know *everything* in measure theory to understand probability theory or statistics but it gives you a coherent framework to understand how  everything fits together.  Basically, without measure theory, it is very awkward to define certain things like random variables or distributions. You can get a "fuzzy" understanding without it but it is hard to do any real work outside of the toy problems you find in intro level textbooks.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I always assumed a random variable was literally just a variable taken from some distribution where the likelihood of a particular value being drawn is equal to its corresponding value in the PDF?

Comment: "Well in that case, your best bet is to get to the point where you do know how calculus works and then start out with some basic measure theory." I disagree. It is clear from the OP's posts that he hasn't had much exposure to even calculus computations, and you're suggesting that the OP (essentially) learn real analysis, measure theory, and then do probability theory? Let the OP actually learn basic computations first before the OP decides to even touch real analysis. You don't need real analysis to do most applied probability problems. [continued]

Comment: [continued] I love probability and love the theory, and would never tell someone not even familiar with analysis to learn the measure-theoretic approach of probability the first time.

Comment: Given a probability space $\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, and a measurable space $(S,\mathcal{S})$, usually $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ a random variable is a *function* $X:\Omega \to S$. Your definition is fine until you realize that there are some random variable which lack distributions. Also, the definition of a distribution relies on the existence of a random variable (i.e. a distribution is a probability measure given by $\mathbb{P}(X^{-1})$) so it is circular reasoning.

Comment: @Clarinetist I don't disagree at all and solving applied probability problems is great and fine but to really understand it, you absolutely need measure theory. I think a more realistic path is to master calculus, then analysis and then probability theory from a measure theoretic perspective. That would be the most efficient path at least IMO.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation I guess. I don't know what $\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}, \mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ are. I also don't know what $X:\Omega \to S$ means in terms of notation.

Comment: Well if you took a calculus class, surely you are familiar with $\mathbb{R}$-the real numbers. $\Omega$ is a set of events, $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma-algebra of $\Omega$ which is the set of subsets of $\Omega$ closed under countable unions, intersections and compliments and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is basically the set of intervals of the form $\{ [a,b), (a,b),(a,b],[a,b],\{a\},\{b\}\}$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. It won't make much sense out of context but once you get into it, you can think of a sigma-algebra as a sort of generalization of an "experiment".

Comment: https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/gsm-126-tao5-measure-book.pdf

Comment: This is a good introduction because he explains *why* you'd want to go to such an abstract framework for something as intuitive as "area".

Comment: "Set of events"? What does an event look like? What is a "sigma-algebra"? Is that what defines an event?

Comment: And I understand the intervals (inclusive vs. exclusive), but what is $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$?

Comment: $\{a\}$ is just a singleton but give that PDF a read and if you can't get a feel for it, post another question and I'll do my best to explain it. Appearently extended discussion is frowned upon in the comments.

Comment: I can't even make it past page xi on Notation. The paragraph starting "Given a subset E of a space X"... I have no idea what any of that means. What is a space? What is $1_E$? The number $1$ is used to define a function name? What does $X \rightarrow R$ mean? I still have no idea what this right arrow means and I see it everywhere.

Comment: Give it time, you won't learn an entire subject in one day (or month unless you are a genius). $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is just a function that assigns to every element of $X$ an element of $\mathbb{R}$